# Rails i18n has_one translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

model:

```
has_one :small_image, :class_name => 'Image', :foreign_key => :sub_category_id, :dependent => :destroy
```

yml:

```
ua:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      sub_category:
        top_category_id: "Головна категорія"
        name: "Назва"
        description: "Опис"
        small_image:
          attributes:
            file_name: "Ім’я файлу"
```

view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :small_image do |image| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= image.label(:file_name, :class => "control-label") %>
....
```

question: why it shows "File name" instead of "Ім’я файлу" in the browser, the rest of labels are correct

Comment: Have you tried to not nest the objects inside the I18n file?

Comment: yes, but already founded very nice solution how to find proper place for all translations. 
check my own answer, it should be helpful for any developer who is working with translations

Answer (score 1):

thanks for this article: http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/which_l10n_strings_is_rails_trying_to_lookup.html

in my case for labels it should be:

```
ua:
  helpers:
    label:
      sub_category[small_image_attributes]:
        file_name: "Ім’я файлу"
```

and for error messages:

```
ua:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      sub_category:
        top_category_id: "Головна категорія"
        name: "Назва"
        description: "Опис"
      sub_category/small_image:
        file_name: "Ім’я файлу"
```